# Automatically Merging Duplicate Excel Cells

Tags: python, excel, xlsxwriter

I have a list of names in excel that I need to automatically merge while the list is being created in Excel  using python with Xlsxwriter. See below:

[image]

Here is what I need:

[image]

Is there an easy way to do this?

EDIT: This list is only an example. The values are not static. I.E. I value 1 can span 8 rows and value2 can span 1.

Comment: http://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/example_merge1.html

Comment: To be honest, I'm struggling with the logic behind this. I tried a bunch of nested IF statements but the merge never worked properly or I would get an error while I was running the script.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask  Rather than (or, in addition to) post screenshots, you should post the code that you're trying to implement, and specifically what is wrong with it, errors, etc.

Comment: If you can revise your question to show your inputs are derived, and how you're writing these values to Excel, along with your previous attempt to merge, then I can probably re-open the question.

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate since the linked answer only shows the XlsxWriter `merge_range()` option whereas the OP is asking about 'automatically' generating the required ranges. The problem doesn't have much to do with XlsxWriter and would probably be better stated as something like: *Given a list like column 1, how would your convert is to a list of tuples showing contiguous ranges like: `[(0, 2, 'VALUE 1'), (3, 6, 'VALUE 2'), (7, 7, 'VALUE 3'), (8, 8, 'VALUE 4'), (9, 12, 'VALUE 5'), (13, 13, 'VALUE 6'), ]`*. After that is would be easy to implement the correct format in XlsxWriter.